# Generate a PDF receipt with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

So I'm building an online store, and I want to send the customer an order confirmation with receipt included. I've searched a bit, but I haven't managed to create anything.

Here's something I found, and tried using, but didn't manage to create anything.

```
<?php
 $pdf = pdf_new();
 pdf_open_file($pdf, "kuitti.pdf");
 pdf_begin_page($pdf, 595, 842);
 $arial = pdf_findfont($pdf, "Arial", "host", 1); pdf_setfont($pdf, $arial, 10);
 pdf_show_xy($pdf, $_REQUEST['cartContent'] , 50, 750);
 pdf_end_page($pdf);
 pdf_close($pdf);
?>
```

So an ajax call will pass the cartContent to the script, and it should print it to a pdf. But no, is it even possible?

Comment: What library file did you add?

Comment: what PDF framework are you using?

Comment: Oh, do I need a library? Like I said, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply using **[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)**. Design a layout in HTML and give it a try.

Comment: Where this should be installed? Because I don't have access to the server php configuration...

Comment: This does not need such things. The package comes in a compressed archive. Just upload it to your server.

Comment: The htmllayout design sound so good that if this works properly, I'll use this.

Comment: This is the best available option for you. I use this for 2 years and works fine for me

Comment: But how would I use this? I've included the tcpdf.php.

Comment: have you uploaded all TCPDF files into server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16365/discussion-between-blasteralfred-and-christian-nikkanen)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you have a look at [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). Clean and simple.

Include the `fpdf.php` file, and you are ready to go.

Form the tutorial:

```
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: So no serverside installations?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of spending countless hours on installing custom libraries and finding out how to use it - it may be more cost-effective to use an existing API that works out of the box.

htm2pdf.co.uk offers a very simple one that works over HTTP get and there are several other providers that offer APIs as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally used OxeBox digital receipts API and its great, You can go and try it for generating PDF receipt without the need of any library. The API also delivers the generated PDF receipt to customer email address and is free to use.

Link: http://oxebox.com/c/developers.php